# Why is Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES automatically set

Tags: android, kotlin

I recently created a new android project, and I noticed there are two files that my app uses for the styles, which is themes.xml and themes.xml(night). When I run my app on my device(android 9), it uses the styles from themes.xml(night) file. But my device does not have a dark mode feature. Should it be using the themes.xml file by default? And will only use themes.xml(night) if I set the app to dark mode or if the device is set to dark mode? What I want is for it to use the themes.xml file, I don't want my app to be running in dark mode for now. I've used the code below to check if my app is running in dark mode and it prints the "UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES":

```
val mode = this?.resources?.configuration?.uiMode?.and(Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK)
    when (mode) {
        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> Log.d("MyApp", "UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES")
        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> Log.d("MyApp", "UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO")
        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED -> Log.d("MyApp", "UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED")
    }
```

I've tried changing the default by using this code:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

But it recreates the activity and I don't want that as much as possible. Can anyone provide an answer why dark mode is the default? And how can I change it aside from using the setDefaultNightMode()?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to support night mode simply delete `values-night` folder.

If you still see dark colors that's probably because you're using `DayNight` theme.

You'll need to change:

```
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

To

```
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

No need to add `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)`